# Can Querydsl support INSERT from a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, querydsl

I have a simple schema for storing links in two different ways and I'm migrating from one to the other. Where an old-style link does not have a matching new-style link, I've been able to use Querydsl to migrate using an `INSERT` from a subquery. However, when an old-style link has a new-style link with a different destination, I want to do an `UPDATE` from a subquery and I haven't been able to get this to work in Querydsl, although I can with plain SQL.

Here's my basic pseudo-schema:

```
TABLE LINK_A
    type int
    src int
    dest int

TABLE LINK_B
    child int
    parent int
```

When an old-style link (`LINK_A`) has matching new-style link (`LINK_B`) with a different destination, ie. `src == child` and `dest <> parent`, then I want to update the new-style link and set its `parent` to the old-style link's `dest`.

Here's the SQL query that I've been using successfully to perform this operation:

```
 UPDATE LINK_B
    SET parent = subquery.dest
    FROM (SELECT src, dest
            FROM LINK_A la
            WHERE type = 42
            AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT child FROM LINK_B lb
                    WHERE lb.child = la.src
                    AND lb.parent <> la.dest
            )
    ) AS subquery
    WHERE LINK_B.child = subquery.src;
```

I've been unable to convert this into QueryDsl. Here's what I have so far:

```
    BooleanExpression oldLinkHasNewLinkWithDifferentDest = SQLExpressions
            .select(LINK_B.child)
            .from(LINK_B)
            .where(
                    LINK_B.child.eq(LINK_A.src),
                    LINK_B.parent.ne(LINK_A.dest))
            .exists();

    SubQueryExpression<Tuple> oldLinksWithDifferentNewLinks = SQLExpressions
            .select(LINK_A.src, LINK_A.dest)
            .from(LINK_A)
            .where(
                    LINK_A.linktype.eq(42),
                    oldLinkHasNewLinkWithDifferentDest
            );

    update(LINK_B) ??
    .set(LINK_B.parent, ??
    ??
```

Can anyone help me finish this off?

Comment: This is waht the docs: [2.3.13.1](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/reference/html/ch02s03.html#d0e987) say about insert, and [update](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/reference/html/ch02s03.html#d0e1006)

Comment: Thanks Luuk, I've seen the docs and I still wonder if what I need to do can be done. It seems odd that I can do a similar thing for `INSERT` and not `UPDATE`. The alternative seems to be loading all the values into memory and then passing them back to the DB.